# mysql boolean on where clause

Tags: mysql, boolean, where-clause

I am wondering which is faster?

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `is_deleted` = false;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE NOT `is_deleted`
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't know for certain, but my guess is that the query optimizer would treat the two queries as equivalent.

Comment: Is the second query actually valid?

Comment: yes the second query is valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Schema

```
create table t123
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    x boolean not null,
    key(x)
);
truncate table t123;
insert t123(x) values (false),(true),(false),(true),(false),(true),(false),(true),(false),(true),(false),(true);
insert t123(x) select (x) from t123;
insert t123(x) select (x) from t123;
insert t123(x) select (x) from t123;
insert t123(x) select (x) from t123;
insert t123(x) select (x) from t123;
insert t123(x) select (x) from t123;
insert t123(x) select (x) from t123;
insert t123(x) select (x) from t123;
insert t123(x) select (x) from t123;
insert t123(x) select (x) from t123;
insert t123(x) select (x) from t123;
insert t123(x) select (x) from t123;
insert t123(x) select (x) from t123;
insert t123(x) select (x) from t123;
insert t123(x) select (x) from t123;
insert t123(x) select (x) from t123;
insert t123(x) select (x) from t123;
insert t123(x) select (x) from t123;

select count(*) as rowCount from t123;
+----------+
| rowCount |
+----------+
|  3145728 |
+----------+
```

We now have 3.1M rows.

### A

```
explain SELECT * FROM t123 WHERE x=false;

+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t123  | ref  | x             | x    | 1       | const | 1570707 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
```

### B

```
explain SELECT * FROM t123 WHERE NOT `x`;

+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t123  | index | NULL          | x    | 1       | NULL | 3141414 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
```

So `A` is faster, because it is able to use the native datatype (as seen in an index that has it), and does not force a table scan due to the way `B` deals with the data conversion (and *does* cause a table scan)

The proof of it is in the `explain` output, with the number of `rows` required to determine the answer, and the lack of a use of an index (the `ref` column) even on the column for both queries.

Mysql manual page for [Explain Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html).

Answer (score 5):

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE NOT `is_deleted`

This query will give you faster and appropriate result.

Because in Mysql better to use Not operator for boolean data types.

Comment: sorry to resurrect this, but do you have any proof about this? based on the answer above and my test, it will result a full table scan, and that is not good. So how you prove that it is faster, and what do you mean ```appropriate result```?